# php/mysql: how to search case insentitively

Tags: php, mysql, search, case-insensitive

i have this table in UTF8 (collation is utf8_bin in case it matters).

I need to search in it for strings using LIKE '%$searchstring%' .

Right now you have to use the exact case in order for the results to show up. Is there a way to make it case insensitive ?

Thank you

UPDATE
sorry, found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203399/how-do-you-write-a-case-insensitive-query-for-both-mysql-and-postgres).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
WHERE LOWER(t.column) LIKE LOWER('%search_string%')
```

..or:

```
WHERE UPPER(t.column) LIKE UPPER('%search_string%')
```

References:

- [LOWER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)
- [UPPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case/234751#234751, comparison with 'lower' or 'upper' can be incorrect for some languages

Comment: What about `... (etc COLLATE utf8_<lang>_ci) LIKE '%searchstring%'`? By the way, if you want "Çilek" to show up in results when the user searches for "cilek", you can use `utf8_unicode_ci`, that is, both case insensitive and collation insensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

Your collation specifies the case-sensitivity.  Use this instead:

utf8_ci