# Case-insensitive find_or_create_by_whatever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, case-insensitive

I want to be able to do `Artist.case_insensitive_find_or_create_by_name(artist_name)`[1] (and have it work on both sqlite and postgreSQL)

What's the best way to accomplish this? Right now I'm just adding a method directly to the `Artist` class (kind of ugly, especially if I want this functionality in another class, but whatever):

```
  def self.case_insensitive_find_or_create_by_name(name)
    first(:conditions => ['UPPER(name) = UPPER(?)', name]) || create(:name => name)
  end
```

[1]: Well, ideally it would be `Artist.find_or_create_by_name(artist_name, :case_sensitive => false)`, but this seems much harder to implement

Comment: Why is `Artist.find_or_create_by_name(artist_name, :case_sensitive => false)` harder to implement?

Comment: If you were to use MySQL, matches are case insensitive.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu because `find_or_create_by_name` is created dynamically by `method_missing`? Maybe it's not harder -- how would you implement it?

Comment: Implement it like any other class method. If you have defined this method, then `method_missing?` is never invoked.

Comment: But would do I access the default `find_or_create_by_name` behavior when the user *doesn't* do `:case_sensitive => false`? (I guess duplicating it wouldn't be a big deal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is for the additional questions asked in the question comments.

You wont be able to call the default `find_or_create_by_name` if you override that method. But you can implement your own as shown below:

```
def self.find_or_create_by_name(*args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  options[:name] = args[0] if args[0].is_a?(String)
  case_sensitive = options.delete(:case_sensitive)
  conditions = case_sensitive ? ['name = ?', options[:name]] : 
                                ['UPPER(name) = ?', options[:name].upcase] 
  first(:conditions => conditions) || create(options)
end
```

Now you can call the overridden method as follows:

```
User.find_or_create_by_name("jack")
User.find_or_create_by_name("jack", :case_sensitive => true)
User.find_or_create_by_name("jack", :city=> "XXX", :zip => "1234")
User.find_or_create_by_name("jack", :zip => "1234", :case_sensitive => true)
```

Answer (score 18):

Rails 4 gives you a way to accomplish the same thing:

`Artist.where('lower(name) = ?', name.downcase).first_or_create(:name=>name)`

Comment: Sounds like this method still exists in rails 4.2 but is deprecated.

Comment: It looks like it's still working in rails 5.0 without any deprecation warnings.  Where did you see that the method was deprecated?

Comment: My bad, you're correct. I just thought it was deprecated since I couldn't find it in the documentation. Turns out it's just undocumented.

Comment: Working fine on rails 5.1 too.

Answer (score 5):

You have to create an index based on the database.

**postgreSQL**

Create a lower case index on `artist_name` column.

```
CREATE INDEX lower_artists_name ON artists(lower(artist_name))
```

**mySQL**

Searches are case insensitive

**sqlLite**

Create a index on `artist_name` column with collate parameter

```
CREATE INDEX lower_artists_name ON artists( artist_name collate nocase)
```

Now you can use find_or_create in a DB independent manner:

```
find_or_create_by_artist_name(lower(artist_name))
```

**Reference**

[PostgreSQL: Case insensitive search](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-php/2003-05/msg00044.php)

[sqlLite: Case insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing/973785#973785)

Answer (score 1):

Talked about this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model/2220595#2220595). No one was able to come up with a solution better than yours :)