# Is there a PostgreSQL setting that I can use to do case-insensitive queries on column values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been using MySQL for 9 years and now have a new Rails 3.2 application in which I am using PostgreSQL. I am getting bitten by a couple of assumptions that I am bringing to the project.

With MySQL, I could set database settings so that this:

```
plan = Plan.find_by_name("platinum")
```

would return a record, even if the value in the db was `Platinum`. With the default settings of PostgreSQL, it doesn't work like that.

I'm sure this must be a common issue. I sure don't want my customers having to type in exact matches to case. I can't find anything online for some reason, I am just turning up 10-year old support cases on PostgreSQL's website in which this feature is not supported. Hopefully it has changed by now.

### Solved:

Thanks to the answer below, here is how to accomplish this:

In Postgres 9.1+, the `citext` contrib module is shipped with the code. All you need to do is type this at the psql command line:

```
create extension citext
```

Now you can create a table with the citext column type:

```
create table people (name ctext);
```

Insert some rows to test:

```
insert into people (name) values ('ADRIAN');
insert into people (name) values ('adrian');
```

And test:

```
select * from people where name = 'Adrian';
```

Results:

```
  name  
--------
 adrian
 ADRIAN
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Looks like this might be pretty much the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model/2220595#2220595 The answer seems fairly unsatisfying, but probably correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the column as `citext` with the [`citext` contrib module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html).

Another option is to use `ilike` with no wildcards. This will still use a b-tree index if one is present, at least a `text_pattern_ops` index if not a default btree. You'll need to escape the `LIKE` expression metacharacters documented in [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) to prevent accidental wildcard searches.

Personally I'm really hoping to see a `COLLATE` option for case insensitivity added now that per-expression `COLLATE` is supported... but right now, that's hand-waving future stuff.

Comment: You are the MAN. That was easy. Updating question with a quick how-to.