# Ruby on Rails - how to make .where method case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method, which works great:

```
def find
  return User.where(:name=> params[:search])
end
```

My problem is that it is case sensitive, so if I search for `"bob"`, it will not return any users whose name is capitalized (e.g. `"Bob"`). Is there a way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def find
  User.where("lower(name) = ?", params[:search].downcase)
end
```

By making the db entry lowercase and the search params lowercase, then case insensitivity is no longer an issue.

Also, the `return` statement is not needed in Ruby since we have implicit return statements.

### How does it work?

You can pass raw SQL in to the `.where` command. `lower()` is a function in SQL, not Ruby, which will return the single string parameter as a lowercase string. It's the equivilent of `.downcase` in Ruby. Now that both the original string and the string to compare are lowercase, the case no longer matters.

Comment: If your table is big, this method is extremely slow. It runs the lower method for all the rows in your table.

Comment: @MichaelKoper If you have a text/varchar column and know that you'll need to perform fast case-insensitive searches on it, you can (and should!) create an index on the function result. Here's an example for PostgreSQL:

    CREATE INDEX test1_lower_col1_idx ON test1 (lower(col1));

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
User.where('name ILIKE ?', params[:search])
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution! However, it only works with PostgreSQL

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
def find
    return User.where(:name=> params[:search].downcase)
end
```

Comment: What if the value in the db is uppercase?

Comment: `User.where(:name.downcase => params[:search].downcase)`

Comment: @jigz. nope, that won't do it. It will only downcase the symbol ":name", not the values in the DB.