# Ruby on Rails database query not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have this piece of code for a search query in my ruby on rails application. It works locally on the rails local server but not when I deploy on Heroku. Here's the line of code for that query:

```
@courses = Course.where("name LIKE? ","%#{params[:search][:course].downcase}%").all
```

A little bit of context: Course is my database model and it has a field called "name", here I am searching for all the courses with names containing certain words as specified from the user, that query word is passed in via the form params.

**UPDATE:** 
Thank you Danilo and Brad! Solved with putting a space in between LIKE and ? and used ILIKE instead of LIKE.

```
@courses = Course.where("name ILIKE ? ","%#{params[:search][:course].downcase}%")
```

Comment: What is the error on Heroku? Please edit your question to include the error stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a space after **LIKE** and the **?**, and you don't need to call .all method when you are using where, it's redundant.

```
@courses = Course.where("name LIKE ? ","%#{params[:search][:course].downcase}%")
```

Comment: You may also want ILIKE. Here is my favorite way to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664100/525478

Comment: Thank you very much, Danilo and Brad! It worked now on heroku! I put the spaces and also used ILIKE.