# How to make search box case-insensitive in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filtering, ruby-on-rails-6, case-insensitive

I have simple search form in Rails, but when I using the search box, I need to enter the name exactly.
For instance, when I try to search for **"more"** it doesn't return anything, but when I do with **"More"**, then it returns the records, So it seems like it behaves in a case-sensitive way.

Is it possible to make this case-sensitive way?

Here is my code

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        star = Star.find_by(who: search)
        if star
            self.where(star_id: star)
        else
            Post.all
        end
    else
        Post.all
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `downcase`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case-insensitive search in Rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

`star = Star.where("UPPER(who) = ?", search.upcase).take`

or

`star = Star.where("LOWER(who) = ?", search.downcase).take`

Either way, this coerces both your search term as well as the `who` value in the database before comparing them, which should get you the results that you need