# Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,EXPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8, collation

Alright, I give up. I'm 2 days into this error and I need help.

Disclaimer: I will need help improving this question and will try to do a good job of describing the issue at hand, what I have done so far to address the issue, and share blog posts and the documentation that I have read in search of a solution.

The Question (also, asked below in context):

> So the question is, why does the same query behave differently when
>   run from Rails instead of from the mysql command line? Specifically,
>   where is "(utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE)" coming from?

The Problem: `Autoresponder.find_by(keyword: '')` fails with the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations 
(utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) 
for operation '=': 
SELECT  `autoresponders`.* 
FROM `autoresponders`  
WHERE `autoresponders`.`keyword` = '' 
LIMIT 1
```

`Autoresponder` is a model that has the attribute `keyword`

I read that I needed to specify my collation. So I tested out the following code:

```
Autoresponder.where('keyword collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci = ?', '')
```

and got the following error:

```
Illegal mix of collations 
(utf8mb4_unicode_ci,EXPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) 
for operation '=': 
SELECT `autoresponders`.* 
FROM `autoresponders`  
WHERE (keyword collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci = '')
```

All that did was change the collation from IMPLICIT to EXPLICIT.

I tried running the query in Sequel Pro and it worked (with and without the collate keyword). For clarity's sake here's the query:

```
SELECT `autoresponders`.* 
FROM `autoresponders`  
WHERE (keyword collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci = '');

SELECT `autoresponders`.* 
FROM `autoresponders`  
WHERE (keyword = ' ');
```

AND it works! The queries ran without errors. I also ran `mysql` and was able to run the query there too. But I noticed something when I pasted the query into the `mysql` command line. It automatically used the Unicode name for the character instead of the actual character. Here is the query as observed in the mysql command line:

```
SELECT `autoresponders`.* 
FROM `autoresponders`  
WHERE (keyword collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci ='\U+1F615');
```

This query works.

So the question is, why does the same query fail in Rails but work in Sequel Pro? Specifically, where is "(utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE)" coming from, and how do I fix this mess?

I thought that it might be coming from ActiveRecord, but running `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.collation` in rails console returns `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Here are my db character encoding and collation variables (and the query that retrieved them).

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
character_set_client        utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database      utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8mb4
character_set_server        latin1
character_set_system        utf8
collation_connection        utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database          utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server            latin1_swedish_ci
```

Here is the create syntax for the Autorsponders table:

```
CREATE TABLE `autoresponders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `body` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `provisioned_number_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outgoing_provisioned_number_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Context: Rails 4.0.13, Mysql version 5.6.22-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1-log

Here are some blog posts and SO articles that I have read so far:
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/fixing-mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations/

[Is "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566602/is-set-character-set-utf8-necessary)

[Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implic)

[Not case sensitive search with active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052051/not-case-sensitive-search-with-active-record)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_server

All of this led me to create this meme:

[image]

Sincerely,

An exhausted fellow developer.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message implies that MySQL is claiming that the _client_ is feeding '' as a utf8 character.  (It should be claimed to be utf8mb4.)  I don't know the ins and outs of Ruby and ActiveRecord, but that is where I would look.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've stopped working on this issue for the time being. I'll probably come back to it in a few weeks. If I ever figure it out I will document the answer here. The weird thing is that it now works in development (OS X) but not in staging (Ubuntu)

Comment: I ended up "fixing" this issue by using a blob instead of text.

Comment: Also, we now use postgres, which supported 4-byte chars out of the box.

Answer (score 21):

I met similar problem and solved finally.
At first, my MySQL conf is：

```
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server     = utf8_general_ci
```

One day, i found that emoji could be saved correctly only with utf8mb4, so i change the specified column's character set and collation like this:

```
  `nickname` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
```

By now, everything still fine, data could be saved and display correctly by java web application.

but when i query data like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE nickname LIKE '%%';
```

error raises.

Finally i changed mysql conf to

```
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server     = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and everything goes fine.

Make sure also that any call of `SET NAMES utf8;` is removed or replaced by `SET NAMES utf8mb4`

[Here is a screenshot of mysql client, notice the nickname attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t86c1.png)

Comment: If you have a ruby on rails app, you can change the config by adding the following in your database.yml
```encoding: utf8mb4
charset: utf8mb4
collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci```
Make sure it's in 3 lines (stackoverflow breaks the lines)

Comment: Please show us the entire file

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error i added the collate after the where statement

```
SELECT *  FROM chat_words where source ='forum';
```

throw the Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

I later chaged to

```
SELECT *  FROM chat_words where source collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci ='forum';
```

this run free of errors

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem from phpMyAdmin by changing the collation for columns to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Comment: It would be cool if you could describe what you did.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when I duplicate my database to other server. I have change my collation to utf8mb4_general_ci and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran now into the same issue and found out that Debian fixed the collation in the config (/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf)

```
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

After changing the collation here the issue is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and welcome to Stack Overflow!